# Easy admin. Как проверить путь?

Tags: php, symfony5

Осваиваю Symfony 5. Делаю админку на базе Easy admin. При переходе на просмотр сущности адресная строка в браузере выгляди так:
sf/admin/?entity=Product&action=list&menuIndex=2&s...
Т.е. если Product заменить на User, произойдет переход на сущность User. Более того, можно даже ввести:
sf/admin/?entity=Product&action=show&menuIndex=2&s...
B поменяв show на edit, спокойно себе отредактировать данные. В системе имеется система ролей, поэтому такие действия недопустимы. Вопрос: где и как лучше всего проверить параметры адресной строки, проанализировать их и если необходимо, сделать редирект. Или Easy admin не очень для таких условий подходит и есть смысл перейти на Sonata? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пойдёте дальше - то узнаете о [контроле доступа](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/security.html), через который сможете ограничивать доступ к ресурсам. EasyAdmin и его аналоги в других системах построены на шаблонах, в том числе и шаблонах роутинга, которые сделаны для конечного удобства и быстроты разработки.

У Symfony достаточно расширений-bundles для контроля доступа, базовый из них - это [Voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html), используя который вы сможете контролировать кто и к чему имеет доступ, и определять это даже в случае изменения адресной строки, отказывая либо разрешая доступ к ресурсу-Entity, либо действию с ним (создание, редактирование, просмотр или удаление)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про Voters слышал, читал оф. документацию, но с ходу не очень понял, как их применять в конкретном приложении. Всем у Symfony документация хороша, но, блин, как применить на практике теорию, не всегда понятно. :-( Если у Вас есть ссылка на практический пример, то был-бы рад изучить.

Comment: По ссылке уже есть что ни на есть самый прямой пример, где описывается как создать Voter для показа и редактирования. У Post нужно создать атрибуту владельца (Owner) и флаг приватности (Private). Используя их в методах canEdit/canShow и создается контроль доступа. Русская документация Симфонии доступна на [symfony.ru](https://symfony.ru/doc/current/security/voters.html)

Comment: Спасибо! 
Пока решил проблему "в лоб". Дописал унаследованный от EasyAdminController метод indexAction, там проверки и делаю. Но чувствую, что это идеологически неверно. Буду грызть Voters по Вашим ссылкам. :-)

Comment: Конечно, не всё сразу. Сначала что-то свое, а дальше - больше. Я тоже изучаю Симфонию после Ларавеля ;)

Comment: Voters вроде  заработал, с одним "но". Свежесозданный объект( таблица ) Post, упорно не желает создавать объект Post по id, возвращает все с null. Хотя все, вроде, прописал. Пока пришлось сдедать:    public function getOwner()
    {
        // return $this->owner;
        return 1;
    } :-(